# COM ATL Threading Model or not

Tags: c++, multithreading, com, atl

i am a little confused about COM threading models.

I got a C++ COM DLL. It is defined as single apartment model:

```
_ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
```

My test app is written in C# and does the following:

```
start thread 1
thread 1:setName
start thread 2
thread 2:setName
```

since my dll is ATL I would expect the name attribute in the DLL to be whatever any thread is setting it to.
but it looks like COM is initializing a new object for every thread that is calling it.

but I don't want that.

what am I doing wrong?

PS:
C++ DLL StdAfx.h:

```
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
```

C++ DLL MyApp.cpp:

```
myApp::InitInstance() {
     CoInitialize(NULL);
}
```

C# TestApp Program.cs:

```
[STAThread]<br>
static void Main(string[] args) {
    MyThreadClass t1 = new MyThreadClass(name1, pass1);
    MyThreadClass t2 = new MyThreadClass(name2, pass2);
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(t1.RunMethod)).Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(t2.RunMethod)).Start();
```

C# TestApp MyThreadClass:

```
public void RunMethod() {
    ComDllWrapper.SetName(name);
   Console.WriteLine(ComDllWrapper.GetName());
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   ComDllWrapper.SetPass(pass);
   Console.WriteLine(ComDllWrapper.GetPass());
   Thread.Sleep(1000);
   ...
}
```

C# TestApp ComDllWrapper:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME)]
public static extern void SetName(string name);
...
```

these are only 2 values i set in the DLL (name and pass) but there are more. but the 2 threads don't write in the same object. every thread has its own object to write to.

this is how i initialize the dll:

C# TestApp ComDllWrapper

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpLibFileName);

public loadWrapper(string path) {
    var filename = Path.Combine(path, DLLNAME);
    LoadLibrary(filename);
    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

Comment: +1 to @Henrik: Juergen, show how you initialize you COM object and how you share it between your threads. Typically you would have to make sure your object is marshaled correctly.

Comment: You don't seem to instantiate a COM object - you just use DllImport. This was there's no actual COM - you just execute a function on a thread which calls it.

Comment: but that can't be right. if i was just calling a dll function then the dll wouldn't save the argument i put in there, right? the next time i call it, its state would be lost. well that's at least how i thought it is.

Comment: I have no idea why the value is saved - it might be just an example of undefined behavior. But you don't instantiate a COM object in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever instantiate a COM object in your code. You instantiate a COM object using `new` on a type from an interop assembly (the one you get when you add a reference to a COM library) which calls `CoCreateInstance()` WinAPI function under the hood. No call to `CoCreateInstance()` - no threading models, so no restrictions on what threads can call what.

Please take time to read [this very good explanation of COM apartments and threading](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/apts/article.php/c5529).

Comment: thanks for the input so far. i start my C# app with 
[STAThread] 
static void Main(string[] args) 
doesn't STAThread call COM initialization?

Comment: @juergen d :That doesn't matter until you instantiate a COM object. No instantiation -> no call to `CoCreateInstance()` -> COM subsystem doesn't kick in.

Comment: i guess it's a stupid question: how do i instanziate a COM object in my C#.Net code?

Comment: @juergen d: You use `Add reference` in the Solution Explorer and add a reference to the COM library there - you get a new namespace with a set of interfaces and objects. You then use `new` to instantiate one of those objects.

Answer (score -1):

Apartment threaded is like that - its the 'simple' model used by VB and C#. If you want to update a single object, you'll need to make your C++ dll use the Free threaded model instead, but then you are responsible for synchronisation between threads.

Comment: why? STA is not a problem here. The problem is how an object instance is shared between the threads. It should have been marshaled, but we don't see it in the code.

Comment: that depends how he created it, however using the FT model would have fixed his problem regardless - as you always get the same object back. It may not solve his underlying problem, but on the other hand, we don't know what that problem is to answer it.